# Get all ancestors up to X

Tags: jquery, lowest-common-ancestor

Given: `X -> B -> C -> D -> Child` I want jQuery to return all ancestors up to the first node that matches some selector.

jQuery `$(Child).parents(X)` will return only `X` as opposed to `X, B, C, D`. I know I can use `parent()` to build this array manually, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Oops. Found it: `$(Child).parentsUntil(X)`

Source: http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/